# Can't upload image in CKEditor with backend Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, paperclip

Iam using gem CKEditor to build editor for my website.

I use Paperclip as backend for upload image in CKEditor.

However when upload image and click "Send to server", CKEditor appear a error:

```
ArgumentError in Ckeditor::PicturesController#create wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
Extracted source (around line #181):

#   <%= link_to(@person.name, person_path) %>
#   # => <a href="/person/1-Donald-E-Knuth">Donald E. Knuth</a>
def parameterize(separator: "-", preserve_case: false)
    ActiveSupport::Inflector.parameterize(self, separator: separator, preserve_case: preserve_case)
end
```

If I use carrierwave as backend for upload image, everything ok. But I only want use Paperclip.

How to fix it ? Thanks.